# First UITableViewCell should be fixed for static UITableView in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a Static `UITableView` with 4 custom Cells. As the cell's are static so it refers that the whole thing is in `UITableViewController`. I put some random image inside the cells. Now I want to keep my first cell fixed at the top of my tableView. And the rest three cell will be scrolled. I can't do it by putting an extra `UIImageView` top of the `UITableView`, because it is static cell. Then, How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ((indexPath.row)==0)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"one"];

        UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 170)];
        backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"default-cover-image.jpg"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
    }
    if ((indexPath.row)==1)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"two"];

        UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sectionHeader.png"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
    }
    if ((indexPath.row)==2)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"three"];

        UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sectionHeader2.png"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
    }
    if ((indexPath.row)==3)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"four"];

        UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 170)];
        backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"default-cover-image.jpg"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't quit understand.. you want one cell to always be at the top of the tableView? are you using storyboards?

Comment: @YuviGr Yes. That was what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Cells are made to be scrolled with the others, if you have a plain style table view you can simply use a header for the section.

If you have one section all the cells will be scrolled under the header view.
To make an easy experiment just add this code

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

And make it returns a string. If you need more customization use this delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. Yes that's right. But for some unavoidable reason I have to use Static Cell. I tried with `HeaderInSection`, but it is scrolled with the `tableView`.

Comment: BEcause you table view is set as grouped style, change it to plian if it is ok with your specifications

Comment: Nope. It is plain style. :)

Comment: Pretty weird, I've got an app with static TV with a header that stays in its position

Comment: I try with all options, but no luck. That's why I have to follow this way. Though it is not a very much preferable one.

Comment: Your solution is "fine" except that it will likely to broke in future or different iOSes. The fact is that you impose that the superview of the view in a TVC is a simple hosting view, but the reality is that you never can be sure about it, but I totally understand your point of view. I would try to create a simple new project and see if you can achieve a fixed header, maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Exactly that's what I'm afraid of. It may not be proven as useful in different versions. Thanks a lot Andrea. So kind of you. Waiting for your reply eagerly. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am used to set another UIViewController containing one UIImageView and one UITableViewController. Just like following:

[image: Add View Container to contain a UITableViewController]

You can choose View Container in Object Library, just like that:

[image: View Container]

After running, it's like this:

[image: Red is static, and table can scroll]

Comment: Nope the container is scrolled with the `tableView` cell.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you described you got 2 options.

If you are using `storyboards` it's very simple. Just add a view above the `tableView` with the height of the cell you want and use autolayout to keep them together, like so:

[image]

you can see the lower yellow view, it acts like the header of the `tableView` but it will not scroll down once the user scrolls the table View down

if you are not using `storyboard` you will have to create the view by code, or create a header for your tableView. The only problem with headers is that they will scroll downwards if the user scroll down

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. But here I am using `UITableViewController` with static cell. So, I can't actually put something above of my `tableView`. What ever you drag and drop to the panel it put every thing inside of the `tableView`. As a result the `image` is scrolled with the `tableViewCell`.

Comment: then user UIViewController, and place inside a UITableView. In my opinion it will make your life easier. If you wish to continue with UITableViewController i suggest you go with a the tableView header approach

Comment: For some unavoidable reason I have to use Static Cell with `UITableViewController`. Otherwise It'll be done easily like you said. :)

Comment: you can still use static cells in an instance of UITableView that is inside of UIViewController.

Comment: Yes, I can. But I have to stuck with the `UITableViewController`. In my case, this class is related with a bunch of other classes. If I change it to `UIViewController` whole thing will be changed.

Comment: got it... so your in my opinion add a header to the table, if you want i can update my answer to show how to add a header with a UIImageView

Comment: There are three things, I can't change:
01. It will be in `UITableViewController` (can't use `viewController`)
02. `tableView` will be static
03. Header will not scroll with `tableView`

Comment: i don't this that these 3 can coexist with what you ask. I'll be happy to know if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it possible or not. But I find another solution to accomplish the task. Here, The static cells are scrolling as usual but I put some extra space top of the `tableView` and put an `UIImage` in that empty position.

Set the frame of my Static tableView with `CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 960)`:

```
[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 960)];
```

It put some black space in that empty space. So I put the background as white.

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Then add an `UIImageView` in that empty space (Here you can't add `UIImage` in `tableView`, you have to add that image in `superView`).

```
UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 170)];
backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"default-cover-image.jpg"];
[self.view.superview addSubview:backgroundView];
```

So the code will looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Set the frame of the UITableViewController table
    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 960)];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // Set the image in superView (not in tableView) as subView on top of the tabelView
    UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 170)];
    backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"default-cover-image.jpg"];
    [self.view.superview addSubview:backgroundView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a normal cell and use it as a header while the other you index them + 1 for displaying

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayPeople count]<1 ? 0 : arrayPeople.count-1;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(arrayPeople.count>0)
    {
        RankingCell *cell =nil;

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RankingCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[RankingCell class]])
            {
                cell = (RankingCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }

        NSDictionary *element=[arrayPeople objectAtIndex:0];
        element=[element dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings];

        [cell setupCell:[element objectForKey:@"username"] title2:[element objectForKey:@"total"] title3:[element objectForKey:@"place"] remoteImage:[element objectForKey:@"image"] forPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]];

        return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 60;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RankingCell";

    RankingCell *cell =(RankingCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RankingCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[RankingCell class]])
            {
                cell = (RankingCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
    }

    NSDictionary *element=[arrayPeople objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1];
    element=[element dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings];

    [cell setupCell:[element objectForKey:@"username"] title2:[element objectForKey:@"total"] title3:[element objectForKey:@"place"] remoteImage:[element objectForKey:@"image"] forPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row+1 inSection:0]];

    return cell;
}
```